# How to report paying having paid estimated tax?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, new-york, turbotax

On 12/26/2017 I paid x dollars to New York state as an estimate of what I owed for 2017.

After going through the turbo tax flow, it shows my state tax balance as x.

Is there any way to tell turbotax that this amount has already been paid?

Comment: clarify "it shows my state tax balance as x". Are you referring to your NY State tax return is **not** crediting your estimated payment of "x"?   Before going further, make sure that your **Federal**  reflects that "x" payment in your Federal deductions.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Turbo Tax so I won't try to answer, but I recall this as being towards the beginning of the process.  Perhaps right after you import the W-2 information?  There should be a point where you can add a W-2, and I think I recall estimated payments as being in the same place.  If that's it, please come back and post a self-answer saying so if no one else answers definitively.

Answer (score 1):

BobE's [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90699/how-to-report-paying-having-paid-estimated-tax?noredirect=1#comment159371_90699) is correct.

There is an option to do this in the federal credits section under "Estimates".